# Which HTTP code is most suitable for when an endpoint is "full"?

Tags: http, api-design, http-status-codes

If you have an endpoint that only a limited number of connections can be open to (think a video call, or a queue for a ticketing site), what's the best `HTTP Code` to signal to a Client that the endpoint is "full", and they can't join?

I've considered the following, but don't really like any:

- `423 Locked` - This usually means that some other client has temporarily called dibs on the resorce. It seems to be the least bad fit for what I'm doing
- `429 Too Many Requests` - This one usually means the client has sent too many, not that there are too many in general
- `409 Conflict` - This one is usually about merge conflicts on a resource
- `400 Bad Request` - The most general fallback for unprocessable requests, but isn't really correct here. The request was fine, it just was simply too late.

Are there any better options that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `4xx` are reserved to a troubleshooting in the client side, you should use `5xx` because your filter criteria (or problem) is on server side.

Most of servers uses `503 Service Unavailable` when they are too busy. The documentation about this indicates that is used to: `temporary overloading`

For an exhaustive documentation about Status Code see: [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)

From the RFC:

> 10.5.4 503 Service Unavailable
>
> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a
> `temporary overloading` or maintenance of the server. The implication
> is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after
> some delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a
> Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD
> handle the response as it would for a 500 response.
>
> Note: The existence of the 503 status code does not imply that a
> server must use it when becoming overloaded. Some servers may wish
> to simply refuse the connection.

Answer (score -2):

Stop looking for the right HTTP status code.

HTTP is a transfer protocol. Together with its ugly sibling (REST) it tries to pretend that it is also an application communication protocol, but it miserably fails at that, so stop trying to use it as if it was one.

As far as a transfer protocol is concerned, the delivery of a request can only have two possible outcomes: either the request was successfully delivered, or it wasn't.

Once the request has been successfully delivered, then the processing of the request may fail due to a myriad of application-specific reasons, but these reasons are none of HTTP's business (or REST's business) to know anything about. Just because these protocols were ill-conceived it does not mean that their foolishness must propagate to eternity.

So, in your case, the result should be HTTP 200 Success because the request was successfully delivered, and then within the payload of the response there should be some application-specific error information (in some application-specific format) telling the user that some limit has been reached or whatever other reasons you have.

(Caching proxies complicate matters a bit, because they need to know whether a failure is of a temporary or transient nature, but in your case it does not matter, because you are not returning a failure anyway, so the request may be retried.)

Comment: I didn't vote you down but I understand why someone do it, since 200 is wrong code as  the expected result in article 10.2.1 of RFC2616 is not accomplished. In this case the response is not OK, only for communication and not entire porpouse of the communication. ie, if you ask me something and I answer you "I'm too busy to answer you right now" is not OK.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I just called RFC2616 ill-conceived, foolish and a miserable failure, so it is no wonder that my answer does not yield the result expected by it. But, oh well.

Comment: I'm aware you are right in several points and I believe something similar, that's why I didn't down vote you